# accessing dll from perl

Tags: perl, winapi

I am trying to access some win32 api function by using `Win32::API` module
below is my code :

The code is run but the result is 0 (no success ).
could someone advice if there are a problem with the below code or if there a problem of transferring the values from perl side to c side.

```
my $site = 'http://www.test_site.cn/\0';
my $key =0; #NULL
my $value ='data=testdata; expires = Thu, 15-Nov-2010 15:08:00 GMT\0';

my $InternetSetCookie = Win32::API->new('Wininet.dll', 'BOOL InternetSetCookie(
  LPCTSTR lpszUrl,
  LPCTSTR lpszCookieName,
  LPCTSTR lpszCookieData)'
);

my $res = $InternetSetCookie->Call($site,$key,$value);

if ($res) {
  print 'success';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling GetLastError to see what the error code is?

Comment: Should you be using Win32?  Isn't Win64 the new standard?

Comment: @vol7ron: 64-bit editions of Windows implement the Win32 API.  Or do you think there's a Perl module named `Win64`?

Comment: 64 bit version of win32 is called win32

Comment: I think perl still refers to it as the Win32 module, but I think Microsoft identifies it as the Win32/Win64 API.  I just want to see people start adopting that it's Win64 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496995.aspx)

Comment: To me it makes more sense to call it Win32 since it's essentially identical with with a different pointer model. The differences from the interface side are just a handful of ifdefs. Anyway, what does it really matter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that you have an underscore in the hostname, which I believe is not valid.  I tried the code exactly as you posted and got an error `The parameter is incorrect.`.  If I removed the underscore (e.g., `testsite`), then the API returned true.

You might add the following to print the error message for failures; it will give a bit more information on the reason for the failure.

```
print Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things jump out at me:

One, you use single-quoted string with the character sequence `\0` in them, which is probably not what you want. Use double-quoted strings to interpolate that sequence to the `NUL` character, or append it separately:

```
my $site = "http://www.test_site.cn/\0";
my $value ='data=testdata; expires = Thu, 15-Nov-2010 15:08:00 GMT' . chr(0);
```

Second, you set `$key` to 0 but your comment indicates that you think it is setting it to `NULL`. Perl is very <strike>promiscuous</strike> flexible about treating numbers as strings and vice versa, so as a result you are probably passing the string value `"0"` to the DLL function (and possibly without a `NUL` character at the end of the string). You might try one of

```
my $key = '';
my $key = "\0";
```

---

Also, check `$!` and `$^E` for other error messages set by Perl and Windows.